# Neural network regression with skewed data

Tags: keras, regression

I have been trying to build a machine learning model using Keras which predicts the radiation dose based on pre-treatment parameters. My dataset has approximately 2200 samples of which 20% goes into validation and testing.

The problem with the target variable is that it is very skewed since large radiation doses are much more rare than the small ones. Hence, I suspect that my regression model fails to predict the large values at all, and predicts everything around the mean, which is apparent from the figure. I have tried to log-normalise the target variable to make it more normally distributed, but it has had no effect.

Any suggestion how to fix this?

[Target variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcZOI.png)

[Regression predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdbAw.png)

Comment: Did you try any other transformations? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have also tried using boxcox-transform (lambda = 0.15), but the effect is more or less the same as with log transform. So not much.

Comment: You can try "sample_weights" where you pass a different importance for each example in the `fit` method. https://keras.io/models/model/#fit

Comment: I have thought of using individual sample weights, but it's not clear what kind of weights should be used. For example, directly proportional to the radiation dose or something else?

Comment: Divide the data in groups, like a histogram, and the weights would be inversely proportional to the number of samples in each group. (Groups with few samples would get big weights, so they don't become irrelevant)

Comment: So you suggest using the same sample weight for each sample in the bin and then do regression on them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computing individual sample weights based on 10 histogram bins helped in my case. See the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_sample_weight

hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(training_targets, bins = 10)
classes = training_targets.apply(lambda x: pd.cut(x, bin_edges, labels = False, 
                                                  include_lowest = True)).values
sample_weights = compute_sample_weight('balanced', classes)
```